# iOS 5 Storyboard comments

Tags: ios, comments, uistoryboard

Is there a way to add a comment on the iOS storyboards? Currently we have a project in which several people are working on the same interface and it would be very helpful to be able to write in the storyboard itself, so you can leave a note to others or to put stuff to remember later.

Something like a bubble with a message on it like "Mark, please fix the logout button, change it to red". Is there something like this? I can't found it.

Comment: Please file an enhancement request: http://bugreporter.apple.com/

Comment: See also: [Possible to Comment on a storyboard?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/193577)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to comment on storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792994/is-it-possible-to-comment-on-storyboards)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have heard of.  My suggestion is to use a View Controller that isn't connected to the other scenes and have a textview in there that you write on.

The other thing you can do in the implementation file is to use a

```
#warning Mark, please fix the logout button
```

directive

This would show up as a warning whenever the project is built or run.

Comment: Thanks ElJay, I didn't know about Marks. In my particular case the guys changing the storyboard are not programmers, so it's not a good idea to let them touch the source code. I think Apple should add something to comment over the storyboard.