# Is it possible to comment on storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

So I've been using Xcode 7's new feature to reference storyboards within storyboards. To add clarity to my references, I want to add a comment of sorts that can explain exactly why I've split up my storyboards.

Does this feature exist? I know I can create some dummy views but I feel like this is lazy and a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

In you **identity inspector** there is a place you can write notes, that's basically your comment section.

1. Select your storyboard Object
2. Click `show the identity inspector`. [image]
3. Then write your comment in the document note section.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### This is a good way of commenting visually on a storyboard, but still isn't perfect and is still a dummy view. I find it is probably the cleanest way to do it right now.

1. Add a **Storyboard Reference** to your storyboard[image]
2. Navigate to the **Identity Inspector** on the **Storyboard Reference** you added[image]
3. Set the **Label** attribute to your desired comment[image]
4. You can now move the your comment wherever you want inside the storyboard[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can place comments inside the **source code** of the storyboard. Since .storyboard files are XML-based, you can write standard XML comments in it:

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

To open a storyboard as source code, **right-click** on the file in **the Project navigator** (the first icon from the left on the right sidebar) and select **Open As/Source Code**:

[image: Open As/Source Code]

To return to Interface Builder, select **Open As/Interface Builder - Storyboard** from the same contextual menu.

**WARNING:** Always place these comments after the first line of the file, since Xcode expects an XML declaration there.