# Commenting visually on storyboard

Tags: xcode

Is there a way in Xcode to add comments visually inside the storyboard?

It will make it helpful to add simple notes or to clarify some complex views designed for other developers.

Of course I don't mean to add dummy views on storyboard and leave it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to comment on storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792994/is-it-possible-to-comment-on-storyboards)

Comment: Looks like your request to avoid dummy views may not be avoidable, based on that other Q&A.